# Why is NSDictionary alphabetical in memory, but not in enumeration?

Tags: cocoa, sorting, nsdictionary, alphabetical

I understand that the right way to sort an NSDictionary is to create an array from the keys, sort the array, and then enumerate through the array and operate on the NSDictionary from there.  My question is, for an NSDictionary *dict, with keys and values of strings,

Why is this alphabetical:

```
NSLog(@"%@", dict);
```

But this is not:

```
for (NSString *w in dict)
{
    NSLog(@"%@", w);
}
```

Seems odd... am I doing something wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's not "in memory" -- %@ causes a message to be called on dict, and that sorted it.  Enumerating is meant to give you the fastest, raw access to the contents.  If you need it sorted, you have to sort it.

Take a look at this free sorted dictionary for Objective-C

http://code.google.com/p/cocoa-sorted-dictionary/

Comment: Ah, that makes sense.  I didn't think about NSLog's %@ doing the sorting.  Thanks!

Comment: I.e. dictinaries are inherently unordered.

Comment: A dictionary is just an interface for a collection that maps one value to another.  It doesn't have to be unordered.  For example, I could make a dictionary out of a binary tree -- in that case it would be ordered.  In C++, std::map has a dictionary interface, and is ordered.  A Hash table is unordered, so a dictionary made from one would be too.

Comment: Sorry -- **NSDictionary** instances are inherently unordered.

Comment: Note that `NSLog("dict: %@", myDict)` replaces the `%@` with the return value of `[myDict description]`, so it's NSDictionary's `description` method that's doing the sorting.  You can enable the same sort of pretty printing for your own classes by implementing `-(NSString *)description`.

Answer (score 2):

Because the first one sorts the array in exactly the way you describe, to make it easier for the user/programmer to find stuff. However, you’ll get the iteration order if you use the lower-level `CFCopyDescription(dict)`.

The source code for the CoreFoundation collections is [available](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/CF/CF-550.42/), albeit without the Objective-C interface. `NSDictionary`/`CFDictionary` and `NSSet`/`CFSet` are based on `CFBasicHash`, which unsurprisingly implements a hash table. `CFCopyDescription()` and fast iteration loop over elements in memory order (`CFBasicHashApply()` and `CFBasicHashGetBucket()` in CFBasicHash.m). The actual ordering is designed for quick lookup based on hashing. If you’re not familiar with hash tables, see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table).

Comment: This is a good explanation also, thank you for the in-depth information.