# NSMutableDictionary Disable Sorting

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa, ipad

I am utilizing a NSMutableDictionary, and it seams that it is automatically sorting the key's based on its first alphabet? Is there any way to disable this automatically sorting? I tried changing the position of these keys and still having the same issue when I call [NSMutableDictionary description] method.

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you want to sort the dictionary? The whole point of a dictionary is that if you give it a key, it gives you the associated object, no sorting/searching needed. Also, I'm sure that Apple has optimized the way the `NSMutableDictionary` sorts it's objects, so you shouldn't mess around with it.

Comment: If the ordering of objects is important, than perhaps you should be using an array.

Comment: My concern here for sorting is because I am utilizing the content as JSON Representation, and I am not sure if this requires ordering? If that's not the case then I am certain I am doing something wrong when setting the Post body or header.

Comment: Do note that if you use the `description` of a NSMutableDictionary for the JSON representation, that will be wrong.  You need to use a proper JSON encoder/decoder.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It only sorts the keys when outputting the description string, it doesn't change the memory layout which is based on a hash table. If you enumerate through it, it won't be sorted as it's meant to give you fast access. See [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4228691/why-is-nsdictionary-alphabetical-in-memory-but-not-in-enumeration).

Comment: Okay makes sense, now my another set of question comes with respect to JSON Representation, as I am sending two key pair values as "Username" and "Password", yet in description it is showing as "Password", "Username". Therefore, does JSON even requires ordering? From what I recall it shouldn't be the case but still. I am using ASIHTTPRequest API, therefore it seam quite odd to me as I am still not able to get authentication for the "Post" method.

Comment: In general, values in a JSON "object" (which maps to a dictionary) are considered unordered.  An API that depended on the order would be, at best, "cheating", and it's unlikely anyway, since it's much easier for the API builder to use a dictionary-type interface that would be order-independent.  (Array values, of course, ARE order-dependent.)

Comment: In NextStep JSON representations (at least those that I am familiar with), ordered JSON "arrays" or "lists" are stored in NSArrays and NSDictionaries represent attributes where order is irrelevant.